# How do I create windows service to run scheduled backup job using vb.net

Tags: windows, service, visual-studio-2005

I want to create a backup service to run database backup on given schedule in a text file using vb.net 2005.

Comment: Thank you for posting your requirements. Now please post your attempt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you wants to create scheduled DB Backups through Windows Service(VB.NET).
Ref: [Create a scheduled backup service through VB.NET](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0440__Windows/Backupservice.htm)

Additionally,
[How to create a Windows Service using VB.NET?](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/services/article.php/c4825/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-VBNET.htm)

If Scheduled DB Backup is only for your requirement then you can go ahead with *DB Scheduled Jobs.*

Comment: thanx. that somewhat start i wanted.